# Why does using two getline function together, second one doesn't take the \n character?

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str1, str2;
    getline(cin, str1);  // aaa
    getline(cin, str2);  // bbb
    cout << str1 << " " << str2;   // aaa bbb
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the 2nd `getline()` not take `\n`, when I input `str1` as `"aaa\n"`?
`cout` should print `"aaa"` not `"aaa bbb"`.

Comment: No, I am representing "\n" as a new line or you can say hitting the "enter" key. I hope it clears.

Comment: Jayant Sharma, best to use `\n` then as `/n` is something else.  Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of `std::getline` at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (bolding mine):

> ...until one of the following occurs...
>  
>  b) the next
> available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim),
> ***in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is
> not appended to str***.

So, in your case, the newline characters at the end of each input *are extracted* from the input stream but *not added* to the two `string` variables.

---

Also, please take a look at this: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)

Comment: I got it, It means the delim character is extracted from the input stream & as it get the delim character it stops and there is no character (in my case "\n") left in the input stream. That's why second getline() also takes input "bbb".

Answer (score 3):

The 1st `std::getline()` reads in the `aaa` AND the line break that follows it, but discards the line break.  There is no `'\n'` character saved in `str1`.

The 2nd `std::getline()` then reads in the `bbb` AND the line break that follows it, but discards the line break.  There is no `'\n'` character saved in `str2`.

Comment: The line break stores in input stream or not? If yes, then why the second getline( ) does not take it.

Comment: @JayantSharma as I stated, the first `getline()` reads in the line break from the stream, so it not available for the second `getline()` to read in.